# Using scikit-learn's WhiteKernel for Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

There are two ways to specify the noise level for Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) in scikit-learn.

The first way is to specify the parameter *alpha* in the constructor of the class *GaussianProcessRegressor* which just adds values to the diagonal as expected.

The second way is incorporate the noise level in the kernel with *WhiteKernel*.

The documentation of *GaussianProcessRegressor* (see [documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html)) says that specifying *alpha* is "equivalent to adding a *WhiteKernel* with c=alpha". However, I am experiencing a different behavior and want to find out what the reason is for that (and, of course, what the "correct" way or "truth" is).

Here is a code snippet plotting two different regression fits for a perturbed version of the function *f(x)=x^2* although they should show the same:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rnd
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import ConstantKernel as C, RBF, WhiteKernel


rnd.seed(0)

n = 40
xs = np.linspace(-1, 1, num=n)

noise = 0.1
kernel1 = C()*RBF() + WhiteKernel(noise_level=noise)
kernel2 = C()*RBF()

data = xs**2 + rnd.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(n), cov=noise*np.eye(n))

gpr1 = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel1, alpha=0.0, optimizer=None)
gpr1.fit(xs[:, np.newaxis], data)

gpr2 = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel2, alpha=noise, optimizer=None)
gpr2.fit(xs[:, np.newaxis], data)

xs_plt = np.linspace(-1., 1., num=100)

for gpr in [gpr1, gpr2]:
    pred, pred_std = gpr.predict(xs_plt[:, np.newaxis], return_std=True)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xs_plt, pred, 'C0', lw=2)
    plt.scatter(xs, data, c='C1', s=20)

    plt.fill_between(xs_plt, pred - 1.96*pred_std, pred + 1.96*pred_std,
                     alpha=0.2, color='C0')

    plt.title("Kernel: %s\n Log-Likelihood: %.3f"
              % (gpr.kernel_, gpr.log_marginal_likelihood(gpr.kernel_.theta)),
              fontsize=12)
    plt.ylim(-1.2, 1.2)
    plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I already was looking into the [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/gaussian_process/gpr.py) in the scikit-learn package, but was not able to find out what is going wrong. Or maybe I am just overseeing something and the outputs make perfect sense.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here or had a similar experience?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue is discussed, solved, and merged in PR [#15990](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/15990).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but I believe the claim 'specifying alpha is "equivalent to adding a WhiteKernel with c=alpha"' is subtly incorrect.

When setting the GP-Regression noise, the noise is added only to `K`, the covariance between the training points. When adding a Whitenoise-Kernel, the noise is also added to `K**`, the covariance between test points.

In your case, the test points and training points are identical. However, the three different matrices are likely still created. This could lead to the discrepancy observed here.

Comment: Great, thanks! I think that is the correct answer. Saying the claim is "subtly incorrect" is an understatement in my opinion. It is simply wrong :). Btw, my test and training points are different. However, this does not change the correctness of your answer.

Comment: Haha, you're probably right. I made a note to myself to check the scikit-code in more detail later and maybe fix the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I argue that the documentation is incorrect. See [github issue #13267](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13267) about this with (which I opened).

In practice, what I do is fit a GP with the `WhiteKernel` then take that noice level. I then add that value to `alpha` and recompute the necessary variables. An easier alternative is to make a new GP with the `alpha` set and the same length scales but do not fit it.

I should note that it is not universally accepted as to whether or not this is the *right* approach. I had this discussion with a colleague and we came to the following conclusion. This pertains to the data bei.ng noise from experimental error

- If you want to sample the GP to predict what a new experiment with more *independent* measurements, you *want* the WhiteKernel
- If you want to sample the possible *underlying* truth, you do *not* want the WhiteKernel since you want a smooth response

Answer (score 0):

https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/awav-documentation/notebooks/regression.html

Maybe you can use the GPflow package, which makes separate prediction for latent function f and observation y (f+ noise).

- `m.predict_f` returns the mean and variance of the latent function (f) at the points `Xnew`.
- `m.predict_y` returns the mean and variance of a new data point (i.e. includes the noise variance).